# Filter dataframe in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe:

```
height <- c('100', '101','102')
weight <- c('40 ', '45', '58')

df <- data.frame(height, weight)

df    
  height weight
1    100     40 
2    101     45
3    102     58
```

Now I want to make to search for example 100 and be shown 40, and if I seach 102 the output would be 58.

I have the following:

```
df %>%
  filter(height == input$counter) %>%
  select(weight)
```

Which is working, but If type in for example 5 any other number that isn't in the df$height then I get this:

```
> df %>%
   filter(height == input$counter) %>%
   select(weight)
[1] weight
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

The `input$counter` is a `ui.R` input. The result in shiny works, but if the input is not found in the height df then it will show `numeric(0)`. How can I make it that the output is `0` instead of `numeric(0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Warning*:

> How can I make it that the output is 0 instead of numeric(0)

1. Are you sure you want the result as 0 num?
   Please keep in mind that in case you use 100 as a filter value the result of the 
   `df %>% filter(height == 100) %>% select(weight)` is a `data.frame`. Not `num`.
2. Even if you use `data.frame(weight = 0)` instead of 0 you might get into a trouble in case you don't use `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` as default.

*Solution*:

I'd introduce the function in case you'd insist on 0 as num as requested in the question:

`zero_if_empty <- function(val){
  if(dim(val)[1]==0) 0 else val
}`

or similar to Valter suggestion:

`zeroDF_if_empty <- function(val){
  if(dim(val)[1]==0) data.frame(weight = 0) else val
}`

The resulting statement in your example would be altered as:

`df %>%
  filter(height == input$counter) %>%
  select(weight) %>% 
  zeroDF_if_empty()`

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution:

```
    # library
    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    # data frame
    height <- c('100', '101','102')
    weight <- c('40 ', '45', '58')
    df <- data.frame(height, weight)


    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


       titlePanel("Filter data frame"),


       sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
             textInput("counter",
                         "Select:"
                         )
          ),


          mainPanel(
             verbatimTextOutput("selectedData")
          )
       )
    ))

    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

       output$selectedData <- renderPrint({
            if (input$counter %in% df$height) {
                   df %>% filter(height == input$counter) %>% 
               select(weight)
            } else {
                    return(data.frame(weight = 0));
            }
       })
    })


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```